# Javascript Square Multi Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

This is a javascript Math question maybe.

Given a linear array of say 64 items I need a function to produce a 2d array like 8x8 as a chessboard is - square. Though the array will not always be 64 items so should divide accordingly - eg 36 items would be 6x6 array.

What I need to do is with an unknown linear array produce as much as possible an array with the same rows and columns, if necessary overflow a few values into the last row.

So 68 items produces 8 x 9 rows with the last row having 4 items.

But it should always be as square as possible so the rows and cols should always equal except a few overflow on the last.

Comment: `Math.sqrt` and `Math.floor` would be two methods you'd employ ... and probably `Array#reduce` + `Array#slice` - or maybe `Array#splice` - what do you think?

Comment: If the array contains 16 elements, the output would be 4x4, right?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a [chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chunk) function.

Comment: yes just updated an exact square, with those extra items in a single overflow column

Comment: *I need a function. Here are my requirements:* is not a question. This isn't a *plz givez me teh codez* site. At least make an effort to find a solution yourself before asking here.

Comment: seems like there are too many moaners to downvote this when an answer was given within minutes. Too many point scorers with too little knowledge (except the people that constructively answered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function square(arr) {
    var sqrt = Math.sqrt(arr.length);                      // square root of arr.length
    var n = Math.ceil(sqrt);                               // number of sub-arrays (ceil)
    var cols = Math.floor(sqrt);                           // number of items in each sub-array (floor)
    var result = [];                                       // the result array
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        result.push(arr.slice(i * cols, (i + 1) * cols));  // get the sub-array from array (cut cols elements from arr starting from the index i * cols)
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a chunk function, `Math.sqrt`, and `Math.floor`:

```js
// create an array of numbers 0-67
const array = Array.from({length: 68}).map((_, i) => i);

// Creates an array of elements split into groups the length of chunkSize
function chunk(arr, chunkSize) {
  const chunks = [];
  const {length} = arr;
  const chunkCount = Math.ceil(length / chunkSize);

  for(let i = 0; i < chunkCount; i++) {
    chunks.push(arr.slice(i * chunkSize, (i + 1) * chunkSize));
  }

  return chunks;
}

const grid = chunk(array, Math.floor(Math.sqrt(array.length)));

console.log(grid);
```